# how to rename a variable name that's also a table name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm interested in renaming a variable in our codebase. It's also table name in rails. How do you do that?

I understand there is something for columns renaming where we use `alias_attribute`. Is there a similar way to rename a variable that is also a table name in rails?

Thanks.

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2015_05_19_181601) do

  create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.boolean "is_completed", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "session_user_id"
  end

end
```

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a todos attribute
end

class Email < Content
  alias_attribute :subject, :todos
end

e = Email.find(1)
e.todos    # => "Superstars"
e.subject  # => "Superstars"
e.subject? # => true
e.subject = "Megastars"
e.todos    # => "Megastars"
```

I have tried

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'todos'
end
```

but getting this error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/decorators/todos_decorator_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: module Content

TypeError:
  Content is not a module
  app/models/content_controller.rb:1: previous definition of Content was here
# ./app/models/concerns/content_types.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:13:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/decorators/todos_decorator_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/decorators/todos_decorator_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the `todos` table for your `Content` model:

```rb
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'todos'
end
```

Comment: What if `Content` is already a modal class under `app/models/concerns`? Does that matter?

Comment: Hi @Les Nightingill, Tried that idea but see the updated post

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "modal class". I don't think you can have a module and a class with the same name, you need to rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nothing to do with `Content` having the `todos` field/attribute that's the same name as the table. The only time that would be an issue is if `Content` was also associated with a `Todo` with a `has_many :todos`.

The error you're showing is because you can't have an identifier be both a module and a class. Right now in `app/models/concerns/content_types.rb` you have something like: `module Content::Types`?  Just change that to `ContentTypes` (and change it wherever you're using that).